# Pandas fill of NA values horizontally, but limited to one forward fill value only

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to fill values forward horizontally, but limited to one fill value only.

See the frames below: `dfa` has some gaps that need filling.  I want the results as shown in `dfb`.

(Note the `.T` at the end of the lines, the transpose the data horizontally.)

However, `dfa.fillna(0, limit=1, axis=1)` fills all cells in the `Name` row, whereas columns 5 and 6 (i.e. the two columns to the left of `7` in the `Name` row) should remain NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[1,      np.nan,      3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,      7, np.nan], 
                    'Age': [np.nan,      2, np.nan,      4, np.nan,      6, np.nan,      8]}).T
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[1,           0,      3,      0, np.nan, np.nan,      7,      0],                
                    'Age': [np.nan,      2,      0,      4,      0,      6,      0,      8]}).T
dfc = dfa.fillna(0, limit=1, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is use forward filling for mask and then replace with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) chained conditions with `&`:

```
m = dfa.ffill(limit=1, axis=1).isna()
print (m)
          0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7
Name  False  False  False  False   True   True  False  False
Age    True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False

dfc = dfa.mask(dfa.isna() & ~m, 0)
```

Or first replace all `NaN`s and then create `NaN`s by condition:

```
dfc = dfa.fillna(0).mask(m)

print (dfc)
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
Name  1.0  0.0  3.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  7.0  0.0
Age   NaN  2.0  0.0  4.0  0.0  6.0  0.0  8.0
```